# sklearn: how are labels mapped to integers?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Bit of a duh! question, but when I read a folder with the following structure:

```
corpus
-- pos
-- neg
```

using this code:

```
corpus = load_files('corpus')
```

how do I know which label is given `0` and which `1`? And is it always the same or could `0` be sometimes `neg` and sometimes `pos`?

Comment: What are `pos` and `neg` ? `.csv` files ?

Comment: No, they are text files, each containing one sentence.

Comment: if they are in separate files then I guess texts from `pos` file must be labeled as `1` and those from `neg` file labeled as `-1` or `0`

Comment: and it couldn't be the other way round?

Comment: It can be whatever you want. Labels do not matter since it's binary classification. You can label `pos` as `-18` and `neg` as `123` if you want

Comment: well, it kinda does, because I need to know, if what sklearn calls 1 was pos or neg formerly. I mean, looking at the input, I could probably tell, but I need to the names of the lables, neg and pos, and not just the numbers. Cant I work with neg and pos within sklearn?